# How can I highlight a single atom in MoleculePlot?

Tags: chemistry

Consider the following molecule:

```
mol1 = Molecule["O=C(N(CC(NCC(F)(F)F)=O)CN1C2=CC=CC=C2)C31CCN(C(C4=CC(C=NN5)=C5C=C4)=O)CC3"];
```

In `AtomList[mol1]`, the first atom is an oxygen. According to the [documentation of MoleculePattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MoleculePattern.html), one of the formats of invocation (the third one) is as follows:

> MoleculePattern[mol, {id1, id2, …}] returns a molecule pattern consisting
>   of the atoms from mol with index idi and their connecting bonds.

Thus, I would expect that

```
MoleculePlot[mol1, MoleculePattern[mol1, {1}]]
```

would highlight only the first oxygen atom (the orange one, and perhaps the double bond that goes with it). Instead, the output is the following:

[image: mol1]

All three of the oxygen atoms are highlighted. Is this a bug in [`MoleculePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MoleculePlot.html), or is the documentation incorrect? Is there a workaround to highlight only a single atom at a time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `MoleculePattern[mol1, {1}]` returns a pattern that should match atom `1` in `mol1`. In this case, that pattern also matches other oxygen atoms. To get a pattern to specifically match each oxygen requires a recursive SMARTS.  The three oxygen atoms should be matched by `{MoleculePattern["[$(O=Cc)]"],
MoleculePattern["[$(O=C[R0])]"],
MoleculePattern["[$(O=C[R2])]"]}`

Comment: Thanks for the comment about SMARTS. Unfortunately, I am not a chemist, so I am having to learn some of these things as I go along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MoleculePlot[mol1, First @ AtomList[mol1,"O","AtomIndex"]]
```

[image]

```
MoleculePlot[mol1, Last @ AtomList[mol1,"O","AtomIndex"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is no need to specify a `MoleculePattern` for what you want to do.  If you read the documentation carefully you merely want to specify an Integer atom index (or a list of Integer atom indices) as the second argument to MoleculePlot, not a pattern.  Here's an example:

```
mol1 = Molecule[
   "O=C(N(CC(NCC(F)(F)F)=O)CN1C2=CC=CC=C2)C31CCN(C(C4=CC(C=NN5)=C5C=\
C4)=O)CC3"];
MoleculePlot[mol1, 1]
```

[image: highlighting the atom index 1 in the MoleculePlot]

```
MoleculePlot[mol1, {1, 3, 5}]
```

[image: list of atom indices, highlights multiple atoms]